# Store json data offline in Android?

Tags: android, json, offline

I'm creating an Android application using Android Studio. In this application, I need data coming from a MYSQL database.

I wrote the PHP file to retreive the data in JSON format.

These data need to be accessed also if there is no Internet Access available.

Comment: Use a database? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage

Comment: Such as Realm. https://www.realm.io/docs/java/latest/#realmmodel-interface

Comment: Use a nice ORM named [DBFlow](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow)

Answer (score 0):

When Internet access is available you should download data from your web server and save to the local sqlite data base on the device. Then, when there is no internet connection, you can read data from sqlite

Comment: Yes, That's what I thought. I perhaps used the bad word by explain my problem and/or search how to solve it but at this time, I don't know how to solve it.